# stop youtube videos opening youtube app in xcode/cordova 1.6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, youtube

I am building an app in xcode using the Cordova/phonegap framework for ios which displays some html that has some embeded youtube player code in it. iOS seems to redirect the user to the youtube app when it hits this youtube player. In cordova 1.5.0 the following code worked, but in 1.6.1 it doesn't seem to. Any ideas why or what needs changing to get it to work?

code to stop youtube opening up and links to behave selves

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];

    // Intercept the external http requests and forward to Safari.app
    // Otherwise forward to the PhoneGap WebView

    NSString* urlString = [url absoluteString];
    if([urlString rangeOfString:@"http://www.youtube.com/embed"].location != NSNotFound) {
        return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
    }
    else if (([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"])) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put logging in for url at the beginning of the method, and then a log statement in each clause of the if/elseif/else so you can see what urls are being intercepted and what the method then does with each one.

Maybe the string for the youtube request doesn't match the hardcoded "http://www.youtube.com/embed" any more? Worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

look at http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html
this might help.

It says to do this:

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<html><head>
<meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 212\"/></head>
<body style=\"background:#F00;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\">
<div><object width=\"212\" height=\"172\">
<param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/oHg5SJYRHA0&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM\"></param>
<param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param>
<embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/oHg5SJYRHA0&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM\"
type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"212\" height=\"172\"></embed>
</object></div></body></html>";

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.your-url.com"]];
```